# Detecting when a PNG image has been "wiped transparent" in Processing?

Tags: java, processing, openkinect

i'm trying to create a game using Kinect where you have to use your hand movements to wipe away an image to make it disappear revealing another image beneath it within 30 seconds. Now I have already done the code for the loosing condition where if you do not wipe away the image under 30 seconds, the loosing screen will pop up.

However, I am not sure how to code the part to detect when the entire PNG image has been "wiped away". Does this involve using get()? I am not sure how to approach this.

Imagine there are 2 Pimages moondirt.png and moonsurface.png

The Kinect controls the wiping and making Pimage moondirt.png transparent to reveal moonsurface.png

```java
void kinect() {

//----------draw kinect------------

  // Draw moon surface
  image(moonSurface, 0, 0, width, height);

  // Draw the moon dirt
  image(moonDirt, 0, 0, width, height);

  // Threshold the depth image
  int[] rawDepth = kinect.getRawDepth();
  for (int i=0; i < rawDepth.length; i++) {
    if (rawDepth[i] >= minDepth && rawDepth[i] <= maxDepth) {
      depthImg.pixels[i] = color(255);
      maskingImg.pixels[i] = color(255);
    } else {
      depthImg.pixels[i] = color(0);
    }
  }

  //moonDirt.resize(640, 480);  //(640, 480);
  moonDirt.loadPixels();
  for (int i=0; i < rawDepth.length; i++) {
    if ( maskingImg.pixels[i] == color(255) ) {
      moonDirt.pixels[i] = color( 0, 0, 0, 0 );
    }
  }

  moonDirt.updatePixels();

  image(moonDirt, 0, 0, width, height); 
   color c = moonDirt.get(width, height);

updatePixels();

     //--------timer-----     
if (countDownTimer.complete() == true){
  if (timeLeft > 1 ) {
      timeLeft--;
      countDownTimer.start();
    } else {
      state = 4;
          redraw();
    }
  }
  //show countDown TIMER
  String s = "Time Left: " + timeLeft;
  textAlign(CENTER);     
  textSize(30);
  fill(255,0,0);
  text(s, 380, 320);

}

//timer
class Timer {
  int startTime;
  int interval;

  Timer(int timeInterval) {
    interval = timeInterval;
  }

  void start() {
    startTime = millis();
  }

  boolean complete() {
    int elapsedTime = millis() - startTime;
    if (elapsedTime > interval) {
      return true;
    }else {
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I see the confusion in this section:

```
moonDirt.loadPixels();
  for (int i=0; i < rawDepth.length; i++) {
    if ( maskingImg.pixels[i] == color(255) ) {
      moonDirt.pixels[i] = color( 0, 0, 0, 0 );
    }
  }

  moonDirt.updatePixels();

  image(moonDirt, 0, 0, width, height); 
  color c = moonDirt.get(width, height);
```

You are already using `pixels[]` which is more efficient than `get()` which is great.
Don't forget to call `updatePixels()` when you're done. You already do that for `moonDirt`, but not for `maskingImg`

If you want to find out if an image has been cleared (where clear means transparent black (`color(0,0,0,0)`) in this case).

It looks like you're already familiar with functions that take parameters and return values. The count function will need to:

1. take 2 arguments: the image to process and the colour to check and count
2. return the total count
3. iterate through all pixels: if any pixels match the 2nd argument, the total count increments

Something like this:

```
/**
*  countPixels - counts pixels of of a certain colour within an image
* @param image - the PImage to loop through
* @param colorToCount - the colour to count pixels present in the image
* return int - the number of found pixels (between 0 and image.pixels.length)
*/
int countPixels(PImage image,color colorToCount){
  // initial transparent black pixel count
  int count = 0;
  // make pixels[] available
  image.loadPixels();
  // for each pixel
  for(int i = 0 ; i < image.pixels.length; i++){
    // check if it's transparent black
    if(image.pixels[i] == colorToCount){
      // if so, increment the counter
      count++; 
    }
  }
  // finally return the count
  return count;
}
```

Within your code you could use it like so:
...

```
// Threshold the depth image
  int[] rawDepth = kinect.getRawDepth();
  for (int i=0; i < rawDepth.length; i++) {
    if (rawDepth[i] >= minDepth && rawDepth[i] <= maxDepth) {
      depthImg.pixels[i] = color(255);
      maskingImg.pixels[i] = color(255);
    } else {
      depthImg.pixels[i] = color(0);
    }
  }
  maskingImg.updatePixels();


  //moonDirt.resize(640, 480);  //(640, 480);
  moonDirt.loadPixels();
  for (int i=0; i < rawDepth.length; i++) {
    if ( maskingImg.pixels[i] == color(255) ) {
      moonDirt.pixels[i] = color( 0, 0, 0, 0 );
    }
  }

  moonDirt.updatePixels();

  image(moonDirt, 0, 0, width, height); 

  int leftToReveal = moonDirt.pixels.length;
  int revealedPixels = countPixels(moonDirt,color(0,0,0,0));
  int percentageClear = round(((float)revealedPixels / leftToReveal) * 100);
  println("revealed " + revealedPixels + " of " + leftToReveal + " pixels -> ~" + percentageClear + "% cleared");
```

...

You have the option to set the condition for **all** pixels to be cleared or a ratio/percentage (e.g. if more 90% is clear, that's good enough) to then change the game state accordingly.